# loading another page depending on screen size

Tags: html, css, resize, menuitem

I'm working on a website, and I'm kinda stuck at one point. (well stuck on more than one, but right now I'm trying to solve this)
In short, I wanted to make some custom shapes, and put them as a somewhat transparent background picture, and I could only achieve that with creating an .svg . I added all content to it, so the whole page is literally that and a hamburger menu.
I actually made 2, one for mobile view and one for PC (it switches at 500px).
I'm having an effect where if I click on an item in the menu, it jumps to that part of the site. This works all fine with the PC version, but on the mobile it doesn't. I'm guessing it's becuz I can't have the same id twice in the same code, I mean i can't refer to it like that.
So I was trying to make two sites, one with name "example" and the other "examplem" (for mobile), and make it automatically detect the screensize and load the right one accordingly, when I click on that menu item.
I managed to find codes for one or the other, but not all.
Could someone help me please?

Comment: Have you considered using css media queries?

Comment: Yes, that's one thing i got working, but the problem is, that the two queries would use the same ID to scroll to on the site, and only the first one works (for the PC version).

Comment: Use class or data- attribute instead of id. If you can provide some code you will be more likely to get help. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Allright, so here is code:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W2Dcx82hNxkOxNRQlxYG3-PjtQOpviWB/view?usp=sharing

It's way too long becuz of the .svg, lmao...

So.. i have the ID-'s to go to when you click on the alt-menus, but it only works i guess for the first code i put it - so not the mobile one. But i can't really use class i think for thisso.. meh :/
I'm sorry i took so long, i got so many stuff came up....